# How to change a font

Tags: fonts, overleaf, fontfamily

I downloaded the family font Play with this link https://fonts.google.com/download?family=Play and uploaded the ttf files to overleaf. I tried to change a word in my document to this font using  `{\fontfamily{Play-Regular}\selectfont word}` but it doesn't seem to recognize the font I'm calling. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use  lualatex (Overleaf left sidebar option) then declare the family using `fontspec`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily\play{Play-Regular.ttf}
\begin{document}

abc XYZ {\play abc XYZ}
\end{document}
```